# Data Access Object is not being Autowired in service class

Tags: java, spring, autowired

below is my code for service layer but for some reason my `@Repository` `LoginDataAccess` is null.

```
@Service
public class LoginService implements BeanFactoryAware {

    @Autowired
    private LoginDataAccess loginDataAccess;

    public void addUserLoginDetails(LoginData loginData) {
        LoginDetails loginDetails = new LoginDetails();
        loginDetails.setUsername(loginData.getUsername());
        loginDetails.setPassword(loginData.getPassword());
        if(loginDataAccess == null) {
            System.out.println("loginDAtaAccess is null"); // this prints on console
        }

        loginDataAccess.insertLoginDetails(loginDetails); // throws NullPointerException
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        System.out.println("setting beanfactory");
        System.out.println(beanFactory.containsBean("loginDataAccess")); // this prints true 
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `LoginDataAccess` - class or interface ?? Have you annotated `LoginDataAccess` ?? If you have not annotated `LoginDataAccess` then Spring will not be able to inject the object at runtime ..

Comment: Add more details including configs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you instantiated your LoginService somewhere, using the java "new" keyword. If you did so, then Spring has no way to know about its existence, hence cannot autowire anything. To validate this guess, I would need to see the place where you use this LoginService.

Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null) can help you.

Comment: Yes, in my controller I mistakenly created an instance of the service object rather than autowiring.